# Common Lisp equivalent of Python's itertools.starmap?

Tags: python, common-lisp, python-itertools, starmap

Python's Itertools has what is called `starmap`. Given a collection of collections and a function, it applies the function to each collection strictly inside the collection, using the elements of said internal collection as arguments to the function. For example,

```
from itertools import starmap
 
NestedList = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)]

list(starmap(lambda x, y:x + y, NestedList))
```

returns the list containing 3, 7, 11, 0, 2, and 4.

I refuse to believe that Python was the first to come up with this concept, but I'm drawing a blank when I try to think of what it was called in older languages. Does any analogous functionality exist in common lisp? I feel certain that it does, but I cannot name it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a combination of [`mapcar`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_mapc_.htm#mapcar) and [`apply`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_apply.htm):

```
(defun starmap (f list)
  (mapcar (lambda (x) (apply f x)) list))
```

Or [`loop`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/m_loop.htm) with the keyword `collect`:

```
(defun starmap (f list)
  (loop for x in list 
        collect (apply f x)))
```

Examples:

```
> (starmap (lambda (x y) (+ x y)) '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6) (0 0) (1 1) (2 2)))
(3 7 11 0 2 4)

> (starmap #'expt '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6) (0 0) (1 1) (2 2)))
(1 81 15625 1 1 4)
```

Answer (score 6):

> I refuse to believe that Python was the first to come up with this concept, but I'm drawing a blank when I try to think of what it was called in older languages. [...] I feel certain that it does, but I cannot name it.

To address this particular point, consider that Lispers or more generally functional programmers would say: "*`map` the `apply` function*".
Consequently, a natural name would be `mapply`.

By looking for that name, you can see that there are indeed libraries like [Serapeum](https://github.com/ruricolist/serapeum/blob/master/REFERENCE.md#mapply-fn-list-rest-lists) that define it, but also that there are older references to this function (with the same meaning) from 1992 (H. Baker: *Look'Lively Linear Lisp — 'Look Ma, No Garbage!'*) and probably before that too.

The fact that Python uses `*` to expand a list of values in the same way as `apply` explains why it is named `starmap`.

Comment: Direct link: https://github.com/ruricolist/serapeum/blob/master/REFERENCE.md#mapply-fn-list-rest-lists

Comment: @Ehvince Thanks, that's a better link indeed

Comment: R's `mapply` is basically just `map`. In fact, R's `Map` is just a wrapper for `mapply`.

Comment: @J.Mini Thanks, I think it's better if I just remove this part from the answer

Answer (score 3):

In common lisp that can be achieved using a combination of `mapcar` and `apply`.

```
(mapcar (lambda (lst) (apply (lambda (a b) (+ a b)) lst))
    '((1 2) (3 4)))
```

Similarly we can also implement it in javascript:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]].map(([x, y]) => x + y);
```

So `starmap` is nothing really new, just a convenient shortcut.